# Core plot: How to hide the plot, axis and labels?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a graph with Y and X axises drawn on the default plot space along with the primary plot, and then I have separate plot spaces for auxiliary plots each with their own Y-axes (the X-axis is the same for all plots).

I'm implementing buttons to switch the auxiliary plots on and off and I would like this to include basically the whole plot space (plot, custom y-axis, and labels of the custom y-axis). There doesn't seem to be any 'hidden' property for the plot space, and all-tough the plot and the axis both have 'hidden' properties, setting these to 'YES' leaves the axis-labels visible.

- What is the best way to completely hide the contents of a plot space without causing more redrawing than necessary?

I guess one way could be to remove the plot space and plot from the graph completely, but this feels unintuitive.

Comment: Try setting `graph.axisSet = nil;`

Comment: That would remove all axises in the graph, I would only like to hide the axis/axes associated with the auxiliary plots. I guess one solution is to keep references to all axises and re-configuring the axisSet of the graph as you suggest (omitting the axes that should be hidden), but it feels like a hack :)

Comment: Yep, it sure is a work-around :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may also set all labels hidden

```
CPTAxis *axis = someAxis;
hidden = YES;

axis.hidden = hidden;
for (CPTAxisLabel *axisLabel in axis.axisLabels) {
    axisLabel.contentLayer.hidden = hidden;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the latest version of CorePlot.

Answer (score 6):

Set `hidden` to `YES` on the axis you want to hide. If you're using custom labels (labeling policy `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`), just set the `axisLabels` to `nil`. Set new labels when you want them to reappear. For the other labeling policies, set the `labelFormatter` to `nil` to hide the labels and assign a valid formatter when you want them visible.

Answer (score 6):

You can set all axes as hidden at the axisSet level, and you can also hide the labels by assigning a labeling policy of CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone to the axes. This solution worked well for me:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.graphHostingView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
axisSet.hidden = YES;

CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

Comment: It's best to add some explanation with the code you provide for an answer.

Comment: Thanks Ollie; I added a little explanation.

Comment: This removes the gridlines when the labelingPolicy is set to .none