# Setting xAxis/yAxis hidden property messes up coreplot graph completely

Tags: core-plot

I followed this post [Core plot: How to hide the plot, axis and labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225638/core-plot-how-to-hide-the-plot-axis-and-labels) to hide x/y axis. Using the hidden property messes up the plots and shows graph with default x/y axis range (0 to -1)

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axistSet =(CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
axistSet.xAxis.hidden = YES;
axistSet.yAxis.hidden = YES;
axistSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axistSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

Through try and error, the following code achieved what I want: hide the x and y axis while the plots shows correct value.

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axistSet =(CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
axistSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axistSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axistSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = nil;
axistSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = nil;
```

What is the correct way to hide x and y Axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the graph will never need axes, the best way to remove all of them (e.g., for a pie chart) is to set the `axisSet` to `nil`:

```
self.graph.axisSet = nil;
```

If hiding the axes is a temporary operation, set the line styles to `nil` to hide them.